# Adempiere - Menu - Window not displayed

Tags: java, adempiere

i have been dealing with a strange problem, in the Adempiere Client, there is a window named Window Customization, now this menu is displayed only in the GardenWorld Client and not in the new Clients i am creating, tried everything related to roles and accesses but of no use, Can Anyone Help???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Adempiere it is possible to flag new functionality that has not been fully tested as **Beta**.
If you login as the **System Administrator**, open the window

```
Application Dictionary->Window, Tab & Field
```

and clear the Beta Functionality checkbox, the menu item should appear on the client menu.
[image]

Comment: exactly, found this off later but forgot to update here.... Beta Functionality was the issue.